# How to modify this string in Python

Tags: python, regex, string

I have a string in which I need to add a '\' in front of every '[' or ']', except if the brackets enclose an x like this: '[x]'.  In the other cases, the brackets will always enclose a number.

Example:
`'Foo[123].bar[x]'` should become `'Foo\[123\].bar[x]'`.

What is the best way to achieve this? Thanks a lot on beforehand.

Comment: Ah, SO.. where you can get +4 for "give me the codez" these days.

Comment: I learned from the answers below.  That's the idea, right?  Thanks to all who helped me out. Picking the answer is difficult though.  I'll give it to the regex way as I learned more from it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Something like this ought to work:

```
>>> import re
>>>
>>> re.sub(r'\[(\d+)\]', r'\[\1\]', 'Foo[123].bar[x]')
'Foo\\[123\\].bar[x]'
```

Comment: This is a good solution (just compile the regex beforehand). It might happen that it be slightly slower than three chained replaces, because a regex engine implies some overhead. But in any case, this solution is easier to understand and would be easier to modify if the requirements change in the future.

Comment: I'm a regex newbie, but with a little help from the web I could figure out why this also works.  Thanks, it's worth to learn a bit more of regex I see.

Comment: @saroele I recommend [this tutorial](http://code.google.com/edu/languages/google-python-class/regular-expressions.html).

Answer (score 6):

You can do it without reaching for regexs like this:

```
s.replace('[', '\[').replace(']', '\]').replace('\[x\]', '[x]')
```

Comment: Three full scans of the result string to achieve the desired output?  For long strings this will perform poorly.

Comment: Sure, and in that case I'd advocate the regex approach. I was presenting (arguably) a conceptually simpler approach for when this isn't an issue. If performance is an issue, a single linear scan (with one lookahead) would outperform regex anyway.

Comment: On the test string `'Foo[123].bar[x]zzzzz'*100000`, 2M characters long,  I find that `re.sub` takes 250 ms (even making sure the pattern is compiled) whereas the `replace` only takes 36 ms.

Comment: @g.d.d.c:  It's O(n).  The regex is probably the best tool for the job, but this is acceptable.

Comment: The strings I need to convert are maximally 100 characters long. So it seems like this solutions will be the fastest

Comment: Of course this only works if the letter is always x; and if that's the case the question becomes a lot less valuable to the community.

Comment: For my application, that's indeed the case.  It's always hard to phrase a question to be clear and useful for the community.

Answer (score 0):

A different approach, just put a slash before `[]` only if they aren't followed by `x]` or preceded by `[x` .

```
result = re.sub(r"(\[(?!x\])|(?<!\[x)\])", r"\\\1", subject)
```

**Explanation:**

```
# (\[(?!x\])|(?<!\[x)\])
# 
# Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 1 «(\[(?!x\])|(?<!\[x)\])»
# Match either the regular expression below (attempting the next alternative only if this one fails) «\[(?!x\])»
# Match the character “[” literally «\[»
# Assert that it is impossible to match the regex below starting at this position (negative lookahead) «(?!x\])»
# Match the character “x” literally «x»
# Match the character “]” literally «\]»
# Or match regular expression number 2 below (the entire group fails if this one fails to match) «(?<!\[x)\]»
# Assert that it is impossible to match the regex below with the match ending at this position (negative lookbehind) «(?<!\[x)»
# Match the character “[” literally «\[»
# Match the character “x” literally «x»
# Match the character “]” literally «\]»
```